# An easy way to visualise chart configuration JSON-files?

Tags: json, charts, visualization, configuration-files, rapidminer

I've downloaded multiple JSON-files with chart configurations from my RapidMiner workflow. See (a partial) example below:

```
{
  "type" : "CHART",
  "name" : null,
  "generalConfiguration" : {
    "inverted" : false,
    "optimizedForPrinting" : false,
    "timeZone" : null,
    "width" : null,
    "height" : null,
    "displayType" : "REGULAR",
    "zoomType" : "XY",
    "style" : {
      "backgroundColor" : null,
      "plotBackgroundColor" : null
    }
  }
```

Is there an easy way to visualise these chart configuration JSON-files? Preferably in a web browser (HTML)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the configuration files is, that you have a way to re-use or share your plot configuration, for example to display a second data set (with the same layout) in the same way.
If you want to store the data visualization use the export menu on the top right corner of the plot.

[image]

You could also use the [Animated Plots extension](https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_animated_plots) from the RapidMiner marketplace to create a custom image configuration and export multiple plots and combine them as a GIF.